# How do i make a button that inserts A Certain text into a textbox in Visual Studio C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

How do i make a button that inserts a text that ive made into a Visual Studio?

Basically, How do i make a button that acts like a Clipboard?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you need it to use the Windows clipboard?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to save the text to the clipboard and insert it into a textbox?

If so, you can refer to the following code.

```
// Save some text to clipboard to test
private void btnSavetoClipboard_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Clipboard.SetDataObject("test string in clipboard");
}


// Read the text from clipboard
private void btInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IDataObject iData = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
    if (iData.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text))
    {
        textBox.Text = (String)iData.GetData(DataFormats.Text);
    }
}
```

If not, please provide more detailed info.